# How to get link of original images in flickr

Tags: image, flickr

I am a new to flickr, today I uploaded an image on my flickr which was approximately 38.6 Kb but when I browsed it they have re-sized my image to about 78.3 Kb even thou the image quality and dimensions were same.

Flicker image [link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/55516877@N05/10135377744)

Flicker image direct [link](https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3824/10135377744_e060de72cf_b.jpg)

Original Image [link](http://s5.postimg.org/5nv224t9z/Subhanker_Chourasia.jpg)

My question is,is there a way to get link of image or original size as it was uploaded in flickr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple open image put cursor on image right click on image,it will show different available sizes click on `original` or simply add `sizes/o/' at url
you will be redirected to new page there you will get the direct link of your original image
for example original link of above image is [this](http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3824/10135377744_8c44891943_o.jpg)